# What is the right way of getting values from database in django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I come from an PHP/SQL background, so the whole data access technique in django is a challenge to get my head around. So far in the djangobook, it has taught me to use a unicode function in models.py if i want to get a value from a database.

```
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Surely this is not how its meant to be done? Firstly, it only returns one column, and also if i wanted to access the table from some other function for another purpose, is the "name" column the only thing i can ever return? Its as if i can only ever return one column from the table - in this case i have chosen "name".
currently i am doing:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(name='test')
```

but here there is no way of altering what i want to be returned, its always down to the static unicode function back in models.py that has to be manually altered?
Surely there is a way of just running a python version query looking like

```
"SELECT name, firstname FROM users WHERE user_id = 1"
```

so basically, how would i write this query in python without having to use the stupid, limited unicode function? How would a production web app do it? Am i completely missing the concept here?

Thanks, and sorry for the badly explained question.

P.S would it be better to just use SQL in django? or is this bad practice?

Comment: Start with a Python tutorial. Then go through the Django "Polls" tutorial. In full.

Answer (score 4):

Fields can simply be accessed using attribute access:

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(name='test')
print publisher.pk
print publisher.name
print publisher.some_other_field
```

Or, regarding your example

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print user.first_name
print user.last_name
```

And, in a template:

```
{{ user.first_name }}
```

The `__unicode__` method is used to display a representation of an object. It is not used for generic field access.

---

Regarding your question, no, you shouldn't be using SQL here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, what happens if multiple results are returned from Publisher.objects.get(name='test')?

Comment: @user2800761 it will raise an exception `MultipleObjectsReturned`

Comment: @user2800761 `Publisher.objects.get` will only ever return a single object (and may raise an Exception if there are multiple matches or none). If you use `Publisher.objects.filter`, however, you will get a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of such objects. You can then iterate over it.

Comment: Yea, so if i am using .filter, how should i identify the column/field?

Comment: @user2800761 The list will contain multiple objects. They will all behave the same as the single object returned by `.get`: `for publisher in Publisher.objects.filter(name="test"): print publisher.name`

Comment: where did "publisher" come from (in "publisher.name")?

Comment: @user2800761 Sorry, there was a typo in my comment. It's fixed now.